# How do you rename "javascripts" directory in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a simple question with a possible answer, but couldn't I find it anywhere.

I want to set my Rails configuration's default JavaScripts folder to `public/js` rather than `public/javascripts`. Also the stylesheets folder as well, but I would think it has a similar solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what OS you're on, but the simple answer, which should work on all platforms, is to create a soft-link from `public/javascripts` to `public/js`, resulting in both paths being available.

On Linux and Mac OS, from the public directory use:

```
ln -s javascripts js
```

Comment: I have rephrased my question. It was a bit hard to understand before.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of symlinks, I was hoping to configure the path within Rails but this works just as well, thanks!

Comment: @SamHunter, We all forget to think outside the box.